# Integration test data in SQL Server database with asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, unit-testing, tdd

I'm still new with unit testing in asp.net core. I got figured out how to test almost everything, but still can't find any info how to connect to real database on SQL Server and test controller actions with data from database.

I have this:

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer("db connection string"));
```

to connect to my local SQL Server, but when I run test, I'm getting an error:

> No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Identity.Application

Is there any tutorial or documentation on how to run tests on a SQL Server database?

Comment: Did you try adding a reference to your main project that is able to connect to the database? Something like:
    using myprojectDBAccess;
or referencing your MyProjectDBAccess.dll in the tests project?

Comment: I often hear that maintaining test(especially unit test) data in database is not best practice.

Comment: @LeiYang, if you call those tests "Integration tests" then using database become good practice :)